# How to delete duplicate UDP packets from the send queue

Tags: sockets, visual-c++, mfc, udp

I have UDP implementation with facility to get back acknowledge from server. The client re-sends packets for which acknowledgement is not received from server with in a specified time. Clients send around 10 packets while waiting for acknowledgement from server for 1st packet. It then repeats sending packets for which acknowledgement is not received. This works fine in normal scenario with minor delay in network.

The real issue is being experienced on a low bandwidth connection where round trip delay is a bit significant. Clients keeps on adding packets in send queue based on acknowledgement timeouts. This results into many duplicate packets getting added to queue.

Tried to find any elegant solution to avoid duplicate packets in send queue with no luck. Any help will be appreciated.

If I can get a way to mark/set a property of a packet such that if packet is not send within NN ms then it will be removed from queue then I can build algorithm around it.

Comment: If only someone invented a protocol that could take care of these issues ... something connection-oriented and universally implemented ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP has no builtin duplicate detection as is the case with TCP.  This means any kind of such detection has to be done by the application itself. Since the only way an application can interact with the send queue is to send datagrams any kind of duplicate detection on the sender side has to be done before the packet gets put into the send queue.

How you figure out at this stage if this is really a duplicate packet to a previous one which should not be sent or if this a duplicate packet which should be sent because the original one got lost is fully up to the application. And any *"...not send within NN ms..."* has to be implemented in the application too with timers or similar. You might additionally try to get more control of the queue by reducing the size of the send queue with SO_SNDBUF.

Comment: The real problem is that in order receive ACK packet has to be send (using `sendto` function). That means packet has already gone beyond algorithm in application. We can perform duplication validation at application level if we can find what is still lying in SO_SNDBUF. I know we can reduce SO_SNDBUF size but that will affect performance when connectivity is good.

Comment: @ManojKumarRai: again, there is no way for the application to remove a packet from the send buffer.

Comment: Exactly that what the problem is for which I am looking for a solution. So if there was a functionality to specify that if a packet was in SendBuffer queue for more than NN ms then remove it from queue then it would have helped. Otherwise queue is continuously growing in network with low bandwidth.

Comment: @ManojKumarRai: and again: there is no such function. But essentially you are asking for TCP like capabilities (i.e. reliability) in UDP - why not just use TCP in the first place?

Comment: @ManojKumarRai: while there is a lot of rumor about alleged performance benefits of UDP these mainly apply if you can live with lost packets (like in case of real time audio) or if it is impossible to tune TCP flow control optimally to the line properties. Given that you implement your own ACK since you can not live with lost packets UDP might not have any performance benefits in your use case anyway.

Comment: UDP has got performance benefit in my case. We have already measured it. Thats why I want to stick with UDP. One solution could be to clear SEND Buffer. I am just think if it can be.

Comment: @ManojKumarRai: the send buffer gets probably thrown away if you just close the socket. Only you don't know which data got send already and which not yet since you cannot have a look at the current state of the buffer before throwing it away.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149652/discussion-between-manoj-kumar-rai-and-steffen-ullrich).